# Analyzing date and time in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, time, filter

I am have a Date/time field (MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss format) in ArcMap 10.2.2 that I want to filter through and show the specific hour periods for accidents. The end result needs to help to show the different time periods of the day that accidents are more frequent. Example: AM vs PM or 6:00AM to 6:00PM vs 6:00PM to 6:00AM. Is there a specific tool in the Toolbox I can use? Or does anyone know a process to help me show these differences on a map.

Comment: Have you seen this http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/time/using-the-time-slider.htm ?

Comment: I think this would be answer your question. Displaying dates
A coverage or shapefile stores dates in a date field with this format: yyyy-mm-dd. A geodatabase formats the date as datetime yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss AM or PM. Settings on your Windows system determine how the dates are displayed in ArcMap—M/d/yy, MM/dd/yy, yy/MM/dd, and so on. ArcMap uses the system short date format (numerical) for displaying dates.
For more information please refer to ArcGIS help manual and find "Fundamentals of date fields"

Comment: please read about Time Slider tool in ArcGIS also

Comment: To complement @PredatorX comment, if your data is a shapefile (you don't actually say what format it is) then if you are seeing the date in the format you describe then the field will be a string and not a date field, something to be aware of. Also demonstrates you need to be more explicit, but don't feel too bad at least you actually said which version of ArcMap you are using! :)

Comment: There have been [many posts here about using time in ArcGIS for Desktop](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop+time).  Can you be more explicit about what you are trying to do, please?  For example, what does your input data look like and what are you wanting your output map to look like?